# How far can we go when asking about beta software?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/645827/how-does-maverickss-finder-store-tags) asks about OS X Mavericks, which is still in beta. There's a close reason specifically for questions about software that's still in beta. However, once Mavericks is released, the question will be perfectly valid and might even be posted again. Also, a moderator edited it—apparently they saw fit to leave it up.

Are questions like these off-topic; should they be left up but only answered after the relevant software is out of beta?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That close reason is basically there to give us a way to take care of questions where the answer is "Only *[manufacturer]* could know," or "it's a bug, that's what you get for running pre-release software". A question about how to use new features or how something works, as in the case of this question, is fine. We just don't want to become a support site for undocumented pre-release problems that will be irrelevant as soon as the final version of the software (or hardware) is released.

Comment: vulcan knows best. good answer.